# What are teachers' expectations on private tutoring in secondary education?

Tags: secondary-education, tutoring

By "tutoring", I mean when parents hire someone to help their child one-on-one. I am referring to secondary education.

This "help" can take many forms, some of which are:

- Re-teaching concepts that were not understood in class
- Pre-teaching concepts that will be taught in the near future
- Homework help ("help" or "guide", not do it for them of course)
- Review concepts before exams

The students could:

- Have learning disabilities and really need outside help
- Have some difficulty and require some help
- Have no difficulty but still wish to have help (to validate their understanding or be reassured in some way)

I know there are many cases and each student is different, but I simply wanted to know if:

1. Tutoring is viewed as a good thing by teachers
2. If so, **what would they expect the tutors to do/not to do with the student?**
3. If not, why is it not a good thing?

*Note*: I'm not asking if tutoring is good or bad, as that might be controversial. I'm asking what is the point of view of teachers specifically (your point of view if you are one, or that of your colleagues) and what you would expect tutors to be doing. Anything you have to share is a candidate to 'answer' this question.

Comment: In my experience, a good private math tutor can have a really large impact on how well a student understands the material taught in a math class. So in my mind tutoring is clearly a very good thing.

Comment: @eternalGoldenBraid Can you elaborate on what makes a "good tutor" or what would make a tutor "bad".

Comment: This is not as straightforward as it seems.  I have known some students to switch off in class with "I'll do it with my tutor attitude". Not to mention only a few can afford it.

Comment: @Jasper What teachers think and expect about tutors does not depend on who I am. I specifically left that information out because of this and I would like to keep the eventual answers as unbiased as possible.